# Use linq expression to filter a dictionary with a list of keys

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary containing all users with their corresponding age.

```
Dictionary<string,int> AllUsers;
```

I have a list of specific users.

```
List<String> Users;
```

I would like to filter the first dictionary `AllUsers` with only the users who have their name in the `SpecificUsers` list.

I have done something manually with loops but I would like to use linq expression but I am not very familiar with them.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You should show your iterative code (i.e. `foreach`) here.  Also, ReSharper does this for you and can be a great learning tool.

Comment: if any answer helped you, please accept it

Answer (score 6):

It might work

```
var newdict = AllUsers.Where(x => Users.Contains(x.Key))
                                        .ToDictionary(val => val.Key, val => val.Value);
```

it will create new dictionary (cause linq is for querying not updating) with all the users from dictionary that are on the `Users` list. You need to use `ToDictionary` to actualy make it dictionary.

EDIT:
As @Rawling said it would be more performant to filter on Dictionary rather than on list. Solution to achieve that is present in @Luaan answer (I won't copy it as some do)

Comment: Why would you iterate through the `O(1)`-lookup collection and then call `Contains` on the `O(n)`-lookup collection?

Comment: @Rawling it depends on what is the size of both collections. Of course in general using dictionary to filter will be more performant, but in that solution readability is better, I think. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

You could filter `Users`:

```
Users.Where(i => AllUsers.ContainsKey(i)).Select(i => new { User = i, Age = AllUsers[i] });
```

The major benefit of this is that you're using the indexed `AllUsers` to do the filtering, so your total computational complexity only depends on the amount of users in `Users` (`Dictionary.Contains` is O(1)) - the naïve approaches tend to be `Users * AllUsers`.

If you want a dictionary on output, it's as simple as replacing the `.Select(...)` above with

```
.ToDictionary(i => i, i => AllUsers[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) method to actually join the two collections. It allows us to get what you need with a single line of linq.

```
var allUsers    = new Dictionary<string, int>();
allUsers.Add("Bob", 10);
allUsers.Add("Tom", 20);
allUsers.Add("Ann", 30);

var users       = new List<string>();
users.Add("Bob");
users.Add("Tom");
users.Add("Jack");

var result  = allUsers.Join(users, o => o.Key, i => i, (o, i) => o);
foreach(var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Key + " " + r.Value);
}
```

It will output the following in the console:

```
Bob 10
Tom 20
```

Only the names that appears in both collection will be available in the result collection

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this

You can use this using `where` keyword

```
 var result= yourDictionary.Where(p=> yourList.Contains(p.Key))
     .ToDictionary(p=> p.Key, p=> p.Value);
```

But if you have lot of entries its better to use `HashSet`

```
var strings = new HashSet<string>(yourList);
var result= yourDictionary.Where(p=> strings.Contains(p.Key))
        .ToDictionary(p=> p.Key, p=> p.Value);
```

using **JOIN**

```
 var query =
            from kvp in yourDictionary
            join s in yourList on kvp.Key equals s
            select new { kvp.Key, kvp.Value };
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the following useful function

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>? Find<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key)
    {
        TValue value;
        return source.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value) : (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>?)null;
    }
}
```

here is IMO the optimal solution (uses single lookup per key and does not introduce closure):

```
var filteredUsers = Users.Select(AllUsers.Find)
    .Where(item => item.HasValue)
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Value.Key, item => item.Value.Value);
```